# PHP File from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Just want to know how to call a php file (test.php) from the below "x:" or "y:"

```
var example1 = {
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  y: [20, 14, 23], 
  name: 'Most read', 
  type: 'bar'
};
```

x: is equal to "test.php"

Thanks,
-J

Comment: Jquery + Ajax = Success

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using jQuery:

```
var example1 = {
  x: [],
  y: [20, 14, 23], 
  name: 'Most read', 
  type: 'bar'
};

$.ajax({
    url : '/test1.php',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        example1.x = data;
    },
    error : function(request,error) {
        alert("Request: "+(request));
    }
});
```

And the PHP should provide the array items JSON encoded like this:

`echo json_encode(array('dog', 'cat', 'mouse'));`

Comment: Hi Justin, the page will turn blank

Comment: Is the code in the <script> tags? You will also need to include jQuery from a CDN or upload it to your web server to be included in the page.

Comment: Yes, jquery is included. all i need to have is that "x:" will call a php file. the php file a query. say, will output "dog, cat, mouse". something like that. thanks

Comment: Oh okay. That wasn't clear from your initial question. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: thanks, will try this out. is it possible that the "echo json_encode(array('dog' ,'cat', 'mouse'))" would be like a query from DB?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure that the data returned from the PHP script is a one-dimensional array and json_encoded.